# How To Evenly Distribute Array Members

Tags: c#

I have an array of `Boxes` and an array of `Cats`.  I need to evenly distribute the cats into the boxes.
My current code is this:

```
Cat[] Cats = GetCats();
Box[] Boxes = GetBoxes();

int baseCatsPerBox = Cats.Length / Boxes.Length
int boxesWithOneExtraCat = Cats.Length % Boxes.Length

int boxIndex = 0;
foreach(Cat c in Cats)
{
    Boxes[boxIndex].Cats.Add(c);
    int catsInThisBox = baseCatsPerBox;
    if (boxIndex < boxesWithOneExtraCat)
        catsInThisBox++;
    if (Boxes[boxIndex].Cats.Count == catsInThisBox)
        boxIndex++;
}
```

This code works mostly.  If I plug in `7` boxes and `10` cats, I get:

```
2-2-2-1-1-1-1
```

I would like a way to do a more even distribution (where the boxes with extra cats are spread out evenly) like so:

```
2-1-1-2-1-1-2
```

What would be the most elegant (fewest lines of code) way to distribute an array of cats into an array of boxes?

Comment: Is slicing up individual cats prohibited?

Comment: In math terms, 2-2-2-1-1-1-1 and 2-1-1-2-1-1-2 are the same distribution.

Comment: You should clearly define your requirement for what a "more even distribution" is, e.g. what are you trying to minimize or maximize.

Comment: You can use some hashing such as Tiger Hash or Murmur hash for this purpose. Check out consistent hashing and distributing values evenly. May be it is overkill but fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int cats = 10;
int boxes = 7;
int[] result = new int[boxes];

double catsPerBox = (double)cats / boxes;
int index = 0;
double currentCats = 0;
int oldCats = 0;
while (index < boxes)
{
    currentCats += catsPerBox;
    int intCats = (int)Math.Round(currentCats - oldCats);
    oldCats += intCats;
    result[index++] = intCats;
}
```

It produces the following *"even"* distribution for `cats = 10` and `boxes = 7` in the `result` array:

```
1-2-1-2-1-2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` by `(int)(catIndex/floatPerBox` and than [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will give you one-statement option:

```
// Note: float here to get floating number division
float catsPerBox = cats.Count()/(float)boxes.Count();
cats
   .Select((value,index) => new {value, index})
   .GroupBy(x=> (int)(x.index/catsPerBox), x=>x.value)
   .Aggregate(
      boxes,
      (_,s)=> { boxes[s.Key]=s.ToArray(); return boxes; }
    );
```

Comment: When I provide a  float cats and boxes array I get a compile error at s.ToArray().